# Stability of the motion on a spinning, rotating saddle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, stability-theory

If we model a marble moving on a saddle
$$
V(x,y)= \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 (x^2-y^2)
$$
and set this saddle in rotation about $\hat z$ with angular velocity $\Omega$, one obtains (in the regime where $\Omega/\omega \ll 1$) the coupled equations
of motion
    \begin{align}
    m\omega^2\ddot{x}&= m\Omega \dot{y}-m\omega^2 x\, \\
     m\omega^2\ddot{y}&= -m\Omega \dot{x}+m\omega^2 y\, \, . \tag{1}
\end{align}
    where we use dimensionless time $\tau=\omega t$ and $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{d\tau}$ etc.
    I want to analyze the stability of this motion near the origin.  Clearly for $\Omega=0$ it is unstable as the inverted potential in the $y$ direction is an unstable fixed point.

Now in

> David, Guery-Odelin, and Lahaye Thierry. Classical Mechanics Illustrated By Modern Physics: 42 Problems With Solutions. World Scientific Publishing Company, 2010

they suggest looking for a solution of the form 
  \begin{align}
  x=x_0 e^{\lambda \tau}\, ,\qquad y_0=y_0 e^{\lambda \tau}\, \tag{2}
  \end{align} and check if there are solutions with $\lambda$ purely imaginary, which would  convert using Euler's theorem to a bounded solution in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$.    In the regime of (1) there is no bounded solution: one inserts the ansatz into the equation of motion to obtain a set of coupled equations now of the form 
   \begin{align}
    \left(\begin{array}{cc}
    \lambda^2\omega^2+\omega^2&-\lambda\omega \Omega \\
    \lambda \omega\Omega & \lambda^2\omega^2-\omega^2
    \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} x_0 \\ y_0\end{array}\right)
    :=M\left(\begin{array}{c} x_0 \\ y_0\end{array}\right) = 0\, ,
\end{align}
    The result follows by solving for $\lambda^2$ from the condition  $\hbox{Det}(M)=0$, where one root is positive so that $\lambda$ is real.

It seems  the ansatz of (1) is quite restrictive as the resulting frequency of motion in both $x$ and $y$ would be the same.

How does one analyze the stability of (1) in general?  Can one use the more general ansatz 
 \begin{align}
  x=x_0 e^{\lambda_1 \tau}\, ,\qquad y_0=y_0 e^{\lambda_2 \tau}\, \tag{2}
  \end{align}
and find simultaneous purely imaginary solutions to a determinental-like equation in $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$?

Comment: You can convert the equations to a first-order system
$$(\dot x, \dot y, \dot u, \dot v) = (u, v, -x + \lambda v, y - \lambda u),$$
where $\lambda = \Omega/\omega^2$. There are two real eigenvalues of opposite signs and two purely imaginary eigenvalues.

Comment: @Maxim thanks.  So you're suggesting the "standard" approach of converting everything to first order; I wanted to avoid this but maybe this is unavoidable.  I actually reasoned that the exponents has to be the same else the ratio $x_0/y_0$ would be time-dependent.  In any event, too advanced for my introductory class.